# envio de e-mail em java não mostra o erro quando não consegue enviar o mesmo

Tags: java, java-ee-7

Criei um sistema onde o próprio usuário se cadastra e a senha é enviada por email.
Caso não consiga enviar o email , gera um erro e não cria o usuário, notificando o mesmo.
Estava funcionando enquanto estava utilizando servidor de email próprio.

Recentemente passei a utilizar uma conta do Gmail para enviar os emails.
A partir daí a função não gera mais erro quando o Gmail não consegue entregar a mensagem. 
Com isso o usuário não sabe que ocorreu um problema e não recebe a senha.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

// ... Demais imports

@ViewScoped
public class Mailer implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private PropriedadesEmail propriedadesEmail;

    private String mailTo; 
    private String mailCC;
    private String mailSubject;
    private String mailBody;


    public void sendMail() throws NegocioException {

        try{    
            MimeMessage generateMailMessage = propriedadesEmail.mineMessage(); // new MimeMessage(getMailSession);

            generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(this.mailTo));
            if(this.mailCC != null)
                generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(this.mailCC));

            generateMailMessage.setSubject(this.mailSubject);
            generateMailMessage.setFrom(propriedadesEmail.getMailUsername());

            generateMailMessage.setContent(this.mailBody, "text/html");

            Transport transport = propriedadesEmail.getMailSession().getTransport("smtp");

            transport.connect( propriedadesEmail.getMailServerHost()  
                                  ,propriedadesEmail.getMailUsername()  
                                  ,propriedadesEmail.getMailPassword() 
                                 );

            transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();

        } catch (AddressException e) {
            System.out.println("-------- ERRO AddressException e "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new NegocioException(TrataErro.buscaErroEmail(e, "Problemas ao enviar email"));
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("-------- ERRO MessagingException e "+e.getMessage());
            throw new NegocioException(TrataErro.buscaErroEmail(e, "Problemas ao enviar email"));       
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new NegocioException(TrataErro.buscaErroEmail(e, "Problemas ao enviar email"));
        }

    }

    // ... Demais metodos e clases
}
```

Classe PropriedadesEmail

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PropriedadesEmail implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String  mailServerHost; 
    private String  mailServerPort;
    private String  mailEnableSsl;
    private String  mailEnableStarttls;
    private String  mailAuth;
    private String  mailUsername;
    private String  mailPassword;
    private Session mailSession;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(ManipulacaoProperties.buscaFile(ManipulacaoProperties.CONFIG_EMAIL));
            mailServerHost      = props.getProperty("mail.server.host");  
            mailServerPort      = props.getProperty("mail.server.port");
            mailEnableSsl       = props.getProperty("mail.enable.ssl");
            mailEnableStarttls  = props.getProperty("mail.enable.starttls");
            mailAuth            = props.getProperty("mail.auth");
            mailUsername        = props.getProperty("mail.username");
            mailPassword        = props.getProperty("mail.password");

            mailSession             = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties(), null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new NegocioException("Problemas ao abrir o arquivo de configuração. Contate o administrador"); 
        }
    }

    public MimeMessage mineMessage() {
        return new MimeMessage(this.getMailSession());
    }


    private Properties mailServerProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(ManipulacaoProperties.buscaFile(ManipulacaoProperties.CONFIG_EMAIL));

            Properties mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
            mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", this.getMailServerPort());
            mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", this.getMailAuth());
            mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", this.getMailEnableStarttls());


            return mailServerProperties;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new NegocioException("Problemas ao abrir o arquivo de configuração. Contate o administrador"); 
        }
    }
```

mail.properties

```
mail.server.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.server.port=587
mail.enable.ssl=false
mail.enable.starttls=true
mail.auth=true
mail.username=peroladooeste.portaldoaluno@gmail.com
mail.password=*******************
```

Email retornado com o erro no gmail.

> Mail Delivery Subsystem
>
> Endereço não encontrado A mensagem não foi entregue para
>   teste.002.error1@transportesalvorada.com.br porque o endereço não foi
>   encontrado. Verifique se há erros de digitação ou espaços
>   desnecessários e tente novamente.
>
> A resposta do servidor remoto foi: 550 5.1.1
>   : Recipient address
>   rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; teste.002.error1@transportesalvorada.com.br
>   Action: failed Status: 5.1.1 Remote-MTA: dns;
>   mail2.transportesalvorada.com.br. (201.148.108.74, the server  for the
>   domain transportesalvorada.com.br.) Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1
>   : Recipient address
>   rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table Last-Attempt-Date:
>   Wed, 08 Mar 2017 05:53:40 -0800 (PST)

Comment: Quando utilizei o gmail para enviar emails, o próprio gmail não deixava uma "aplicação menos segura" acessar minha conta, tive que ir no gmail e desabilitar uma opção de segurança para deixar minha aplicação acessar a conta e enviar os emails.

Comment: Eu estou conseguindo enviar os emails. Meu problema é se o usuário informa um email invalido e o gmail não consegue enviar o erro AddressException por exemplo não é gerado.

Comment: Qual *e-mail* inválido você está utilizando para teste? O `AddressException` ocorre durante o *parse* da `String` para criar um objeto `InternetAddress` se o formato do *pattern* do *email* for inválido, ou seja, nesse momento você ainda não está conectado  ao *gmail*. A exceção lançada quando não se encontra o destinatário é `SendFailedException` durante a execução do método `sendMessage` da classe `Transport`.

Comment: Coloquei o SendFailedException como sugerido mas continuo não recebendo a exceção no sistema.
Só recebo um e-mail no próprio gmail informando o erro.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e inclui o e-mail que o gmail te enviou. Hoje em dia até pra configurar o Outlook pra usar o Gmail precisa ir no gmail e dar permissão. Com a sua aplicação não deve ser diferente.

Comment: Pergunta editada como sugerido.

Comment: Enquanto está recebendo sua requisição de envio de email, o Gmail não acusa que o email destinatário é inválido porque ele não é inválido - ele apenas não existe no provedor de destino; por isso não há nenhuma exceção. E o email de fato é enviado para o email destinatário! O que ocorre a seguir é que o provedor do email destinatário identifica que o email não existe lá e então responde com outro email. Se você tentar informar um destinatário inexistente de Gmail, como é o próprio Gmail que está enviando ele tem como verificar isso no ato e provavelmente haverá exceção.

Comment: E existe alguma forma de tratar isso?

Comment: @Marcelo Vai ter que mudar a lógica do teu sistema de acordo com os teus requisitos. Por exemplo: você poderia não enviar senha mas sim deixar que a pessoa informe uma; daí você envia um email com um link incluindo um hash onde a pessoa clicando confirma que o email é dela mesmo, e só então o email se torna confiável para você enviar novas senhas no futuro se for o caso. Você pode monitorar respostas ao email enviado para ver se o provedor rejeitou, mas veja que isso não serve pra muita coisa porque a pessoa pode entrar, mesmo sem querer, com um email existente mas que não pertence a ela.

Comment: Mas mesmo deixando o usuário informar a senha enviando um link para confirmar cairia no mesmo problema.
De qualquer forma obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**O problema em questão é o e-mail ser digitado errado.** ( não que o e-mail seja inválido, ele simplesmente é um e-mail válido que não existe)

> Uma coisa simples que você pode fazer que não resolve completamente mas pode
>   minimizar que as pessoas digitem e-mail errado é pôr pra digitarem duas
>   vezes e dar erro se os dois campos não estiverem iguais, além da verificação com expressão regular sobre a validade do e-mail.

De acordo com o e-mail que o Gmail te enviou, o e-mail `teste.002.error1@transportesalvorada.com.br` não existe.

Não deu erro porque **o e-mail foi enviado corretamente**. Só que pra um endereço que não existe.

Quando seu e-mail chegou no servidor do domínio transportesalvorada.com.br esse servidor olhou na tabela de e-mails e viu que esse e-mail não existia e enviou a resposta pro gmail falando que o mesmo não existia. A resposta foi pro gmail pq o e-mail enviado saiu do servidor de lá.

*Se o carteiro leva uma carta pra uma residência em que o endereço está errado ela retorna pro remetente. Perceba que a carta foi enviada e quem enviou só ficou sabendo que o endereço estava errado depois que a carta voltou.*

Se apenas fazer a pessoa conferir se está digitando certo não é suficiente, você pode tentar procurar algum serviço para validar e-mails antes de enviá-los. Segue um serviço: http://www.verifyemailaddress.org/email-verification-api.html

Testando no site http://www.verifyemailaddress.org/ vi que o e-mail `teste.002.error1@transportesalvorada.com.br` não existia, mas `teste.002@transportesalvorada.com.br` existe.

Esse site envia um e-mail e inicia uma conversa entre servidores para verificar se o e-mail existe.

```
MX record found: mail2.transportesalvorada.com.br (Priority 5)
MX record found: mail3.transportesalvorada.com.br (Priority 5)
Connecting to mail2.transportesalvorada.com.br
Connected to mail2.transportesalvorada.com.br
Dialog with mail2.transportesalvorada.com.br ok
------------------------------------------------------------
220 mail3.transportesalvorada.com.br running OSTec Mail Server 3000
HELO verifyemailaddress.org
250 mail3.transportesalvorada.com.br
MAIL FROM: <noreply@verifyemailaddress.org>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: <teste.002@transportesalvorada.com.br>
250 2.1.5 Ok
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
------------------------------------------------------------
Email address teste.002@transportesalvorada.com.br accepted
```

Assuntos relacionados:
Comandos SMTP:

http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference.htm

Páginas relacionadas de pessoas que tentaram fazer essa validação de existência de um e-mail com Java com algum sucesso:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514005/how-to-check-mail-address-is-exists-or-not

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0452.html

Answer (score 1):

Temo que o único jeito de resolver esse problema seja acessar periodicamente os e-mails do Gmail e procurar pela mensagem de retorno.

E-mail é um protocolo que foi mais ou menos estabilizado na década de 1970, e não é um protocolo de tempo real. Os MTA (*Mail Transport Agent*), como os do Gmail, têm a liberdade de segurar o e-mail por tempo indeterminado e fazer várias tentativas de entrega antes de desistirem. Eles podem até fazer uma entrega indireta, mandando para outro servidor de e-mail, e esse outro ser o encarregado de entregar para o destinatário final (embora eu duvide que algum sistema funcione dessa maneira nos dias de hoje). Se funcionava com o seu servidor de e-mail próprio, é porque ele fazia uma tentativa de entrega imediatamente, e já retornava o erro em caso de falha. O Gmail não é assim, e o aviso de falha deles é feito por e-mail.